# Displaying Colors in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there any way to convert a hex (or RGB, or what-have-you) color to an actual color in SSMS? For instance, instead of returning the varchar value "#3F3FBF", it would instead render a cell with no text and a blue background.

Comment: No. SSMS is not a web browser, it is data tool.

Comment: https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-results-grid-visualizers-feature

Comment: Someone could probably make this into a SQL Operations Studio extension.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/status-bar-database-engine-query-editor?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @LukaszSzozda That's cool, but OP would have to transform their varchar hex color value into a hex encoded jpg or png to make use of that (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @CR241 That's a cool feature, but OP literally wants the cell in the SQL results window that is displaying this varchar hex value to be painted the color represented by that hex color.

Comment: @SeanLange Not planning to do anything fancy - it would simply remove a step from the steps taken to debug a specific query. If it's not possible, could you submit that as an answer?

Comment: @JNevill Well, he could extend visualizer with template to open in webbrowser and prepare vey simple html page with specific background - just idea :)

Comment: You could add a custom report (rdl) to SSMS that does this but obviously not very practical if the need is one off /adhoc for this query

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Ah! I see. Creating a visualizer to open in a web browser and then doing like `SELECT '<html><body bgcolor="' + thiscolumn + '"></body></html>' as htmlcolor FROM table` or something like that. Not exactly what they are looking for, but it's reasonable.

Comment: Pleas have a look into this article http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Management+Studio+(SSMS)/101920/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this natively. There are some third party extensions that might support this but nothing out of the box for this ability.